# How do I prevent previous screen splash when moving to another activity in android

Tags: android

I have an activity which has a button, upon clicking that button the screen changes to a empty screen with just a progress circle. Then after 30 seconds it should show the next screen, but before this screen it is showing first activiy for a second and then switching to this one.

For Example:

```
Screen1-> Screen2-> Screen3-> Screen4
```

When moving from `screen3` to `screen4`, `screen2` is displayed for a second. How do i prevent that?

Also I need to be able to go back to screen2 from screen4 on back press.

I searched many similar questions on SO,but none seem to work for me, for example. Giving a `finish()` call in screen2, the application does not even start screen2 stays in screen1.

Also tried `setVisible(false)`, this does not work in case I click back button in screen4, it displays blank screen instead of screen2.

Comment: Add your code you tried

Comment: try adding overridePendingTransition(0, 0) with intent

Comment: make your screen2 `android:noHistory="true"` in manifest file

Comment: share your code.

Comment: You should post your code to get a clear image of your problem. when the Screen3 activity gets finished?

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys but both your solutions didnt work, it is still the same way as i explained in the problem

Comment: @Joe after 18 seconds of its appearance, it finishes

Comment: I found the solution to my problem, answer is posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies if I did not make the question clear, Screen2 is an activity which starts a service while Screen3 is active and then stops the service when the app moves to Screen4.

I got this solution:

```
registerReceiver(finishCallReceiver,new IntentFilter("Done"));
finishCallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            finish();
        }
    };
```

Then in the service I just call

```
Intent intent = new Intent("Done");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Also register the Broadcast Receiver in onResume of the Activity.